# Popup is not a proper child of its parent window?

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I'm trying to create a stylish window with icon in the top-right corner that is partly outside the window boundary. Since this is not directly possible (content falling outside the window is clipped), I'm using a `Popup` control for it.

```
<Popup Placement="Right" HorizontalOffset="-80" VerticalOffset="-40" IsOpen="True" AllowsTransparency="True"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}">
  <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/graphics/AdminIcon.png" Stretch="None" />
</Popup>
```

It works fine, as long as I don't switch between windows. Thereupon it looks like the Popup is neither a proper child of the `Window`, nor a fully separate window of its own; something in-between.

I'll try to explain it with two images:

**Image1: Window loaded and popup showing nicely in the right-top corner:**

[image: Image1: Window loaded]

**Image2: ALT + TAB: Notepad somehow injects itself between Popup and Window**

[image: Image2: Notepad between popup and window]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a Popup you may use a borderless, transparent Window:

```
<Window ...
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="{x:Null}"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="Window_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0,20,0,0" Background="White">
            ... window content goes here     
        </Grid>
        <Image
            Source="/graphics/AdminIcon.png" Stretch="None"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with this `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler

```
private void Window_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DragMove();
}
```

and perhaps a close button somewhere.

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. Are you suggesting that I use this `Window` in place of my `Popup`? How do I put it inside the main `Window`; through code? Why do I need `MouseLeftButtonDown` handler? (main window is not movable or resizable).

Comment: No, my suggestion is to make your "parent window" borderless and transparent. By setting a top margin on the inner Grid, the non-transparent window content is moved down to separate the icon from the background.